# Get an array of corresponding values in a reference array from very big input array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter

I have the following array:

```
table = np.array([
[1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0],
[1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0],
...
[2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 1.0],
[8.0, 9.0, 7.0, 2.0]])
```

Let's name the different columns respectively by ['a', 'b', 'm', 'n'].

"table" is my my reference table where I want to extract 'm' and 'n' given 'a' and 'b' contained in a list we will call 'my_list'. In that list, we allow duplicate pairs (a, b).

**N.B.: Here list can be referred as array (not in the python sense)**

**It is easier to do it with for loop. But, for my problem, my list 'my_list' can contain more than 100000 pairs (a, b) so doing it with for loop is not optimal for my work.
How can I do it with numpy functions or pandas functions in a few lines (1 to 3 lines)?**

An example of what I want: Given the following list

```
my_list = np.array([
[1.0, 2.0],
[1.0, 2.0],
[8.0, 9.0]])
```

I want to have the following result:

```
results = np.array([
[5.0, 3.0],
[5.0, 3.0],
[7.0, 2.0]])
```

Thank you in advance

**Edit 1: equivalence with for loop**

Here is the equivalent with for loop (simplest way with for loop without dichotomous search):

```
result = []
for x in my_list:
    for y in table:
        if (x[0] == y[0]) and (x[1] == y[1]):
            result.append([y[2], y[3]])
        break

print(results)
```

Comment: state your operation in the for loop since your task is not clear to me.

Comment: @sehan2 I just put it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach using **pandas** is to perform **inner [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**

```
pd.DataFrame(table).merge(pd.DataFrame(my_list))[[2, 3]].to_numpy()
```

---

```
array([[5., 3.],
       [5., 3.],
       [7., 2.]])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I hope that in terms of computing time, it is optimal.

Comment: Yes, I believe this should be faster than a loop based approach when there are lots of matching pairs.